# What are the steps to connect into a HTTPS site with a SSL self-signed certificate?

Tags: android, https, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am stuck with this problem for 3 days with no avail to solve this issue. I have searched this site for answers and tried them myself. None of them worked for me. When I tried the solutions here, there are 2 types of output I get on my WebView.

1. WebView displays a white screen
2. WebView displays: Web Page is unavailable.

What I need are steps to overcome my problems. The website I am using to test connection is `https://www.lokshop.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve this issue. And I came up with a step-by-step tutorial for people to use and a way to log my toughest problems down!

http://droidos-coding.blogspot.com/

Comment: You implementation does not load the images, I see all the images empty with rectangle instead. Even after adding the base url as first parameter to loadDataWithBaseURL instead null.